# .NET Native optimization breaks an application

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, .net-native

In one of the applications I've encountered an error associated with the optimization of code.

I tried to repeat this behavior in the test application. The application is available on GitHub:  https://github.com/altk/NullableError

The error occurs only when you compile using .NET Native, but not everywhere. Error reproduces on few PCs.

The application code is very simple. It must prints to the console:

-------------- ELSE --------------
-------------- SUCCESS --------------

But by reason of the optimization it prints:

-------------- ELSE --------------
-------------- FAIL --------------

All code of the application:

```
#define DEBUG
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace NullableError
{
    sealed partial class App
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<String, String> _dictionary = new Dictionary<String, String>();

        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Execute();
            Exit();
        }

        private Int64? NullableInt64
        {
            get
            {
                var resultString = this[nameof(NullableInt64)];
                return String.IsNullOrEmpty(resultString) ? default(Int64?) : Int64.Parse(resultString);
            }
            //-----FIX VARIANT------
            //UNCOMMENT NEXT LINE TO FIX 
            //[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImpl(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]
            set
            {
                //-----FIX VARIANT------
                //REPLACE WITH 
                //this[nameof(NullableInt64)] = value != null ? value.Value.ToString() : null;
                this[nameof(NullableInt64)] = value?.ToString();
            }
        }

        private Int64? AnotherNullableInt64
        {
            get
            {
                var resultString = this[nameof(AnotherNullableInt64)];
                return String.IsNullOrEmpty(resultString) ? default(Int64?) : Int64.Parse(resultString);
            }
            set { this[nameof(AnotherNullableInt64)] = value?.ToString(); }
        }

        private void Execute()
        {
            //-----FIX VARIANT------
            //REPLACE WITH IF-ELSE WITH
            //NullableInt64 = (DateTimeOffset.Now - DateTimeOffset.MinValue).TotalMilliseconds < 0 ? (Int64?) 125 : null;
            if ((DateTimeOffset.Now - DateTimeOffset.MinValue).TotalMilliseconds < 0)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("-------------- IF --------------");
                NullableInt64 = 125;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("-------------- ELSE --------------");
                NullableInt64 = null;
            }

            //-----FIX VARIANT------
            //REPLACE WITH 
            //AnotherNullableInt64 = 0;
            AnotherNullableInt64 = null;

            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("-------------- {0} --------------", this[nameof(NullableInt64)] == "0" ? "FAIL" : "SUCCESS"));
        }

        private String this[String key]
        {
            get
            {
                String result;
                return _dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out result) ? result : null;
            }
            set { _dictionary[key] = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question - just the output lines and the associated control statements will do.

Comment: Not the whole code **just** the lines that demonstrate the error with any relevant definitions.

Comment: @ChrisF: I suspect that code is already as minimal as it can get while still being reproducible.

Comment: what optimization?   the debug print ? ist that part of the problem?

Comment: @ChrisF code is small. If I leave only Execute() method nobody will understand problem.

Comment: also isnt that line casting the nullableint64 to a string since you compare with string "0", probably you should check for null or 0 ?

Comment: @Thorarins boxing? I get string in this[nameof(NullableInt64)]

Comment: This is pretty normal, you have .NET Native on your machine because it is not without bugs.  Let's you find out that your app is borken before you submit it to the store.  Nobody here can fix it for you, the workaround you found is already good enough, proper place to report bugs is at connect.microsoft.com.

Comment: @HansPassant but I can undestand this unpredictable behavior. Maybe there is some problems behind the scene?

Comment: @Fabjan Try to use .NET Native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft confirmed this bug.
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2164313/net-native-optimization-breaks-an-application#

It will be fixed in upcoming VS 2015 Update 2